# MAMP XAMPP WAMP nothing works properly

Tags: wordpress

I have a big problem that i am trying to resolve and nothing works.. I installed mamp for windws and wordpress locally with no problems but now i am encountering a big problem.. I can not upload a picture no matter the size.. It keeps telling me:
The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels.

Tried to use other browser the problem persists, tried to delete all the browser memory cashe and last installed new servers like xampp and wamp and the problem still exists.. Honestly i think i am going to lose my nerves with this.. Why there is always a problem before i start to work?!?!? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: This may be something you have already tried but, have you tried to upload a smaller image(width/height) as well as filesize?

Comment: like yes.. The images are 500x500 30kb.. maximum upload size is 64mb on my server.. please some other solution.. i am getting my nerves trained

Comment: i found a solution.. the solution was to use a php 7 instead of 8..